# Serilog sending blank CorrelationId to Seq logger

Tags: .net-core, serilog, seq-logging

I'm using Serilog and Seq in a .net core web api to handle the logging. I've added a reference to Steve Gordon's [CorrelationId Middleware](https://github.com/stevejgordon/CorrelationId) to get the X-Correlation-ID from the headers (or create a new one) to update the TraceIdentifier.

I've then added another middleware class to push the correlation id into the log context, but this isn't working correctly:

```
public class LogCorrelationIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public LogCorrelationIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // doesn't work - blank CorrelationId in Seq
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", context.Request.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier)) { return _next(context); }

        // works - correct CorrelationId2 in Seq 
        //using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId2", context.Request.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier)) { return _next(context); }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: For a quick fix I'm just logging the TraceIdentifier as 'OriginId' instead of 'CorrelationId'.  As it's only used for filtering in the logs it makes little difference

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me when I do the following (not as middleware):

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", "This is a test..."))
{
    Log.Write(level, exception, messageTemplate, propertyValues);
}
```

So I suspect that it's your `CorrelationId` being overwritten by ASP.NET Core MVC as eluded to here:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/59

Some background to the issue and their plan to deal with it in `3.0` is also here:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5918

Apologies that this isn't a "fix", however I had the same issue and was able to work around it by adding a level of indirection between the log call (in my code) and the call  to Log.Write (as shown above).

Comment: More thinking on this one... It's not perfect, as you'll get your correlation id in the cases where you call `LogWrapper.Foo(...)`, however you'll not have it on other logging that's happening pre-post your code... Will probably just have to wait until they fix this in 3.0. Apologies.

Comment: Some more info here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9491 and here: https://github.com/stevejgordon/CorrelationId :)